# Logcat spam on Android (Galaxy Tab 4)

Tags: android, gallery, logcat, spam

I'm developing an application for Android Tablets, and I currently use a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.
I use the logcat to debug my application, but, for some reason, I have these messages from "com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker".

I don't know what it is, and if it's related to my application. I close mine, but it still spam in my logcat.
I know that I can filter by application, but I have too many messages from the other application so the ones of mine are deleted and I can't see what I want.

It seems to be a problem of pictures, maybe it is because I have thousands of pictures in my device? I need them for my application.
Some examples of what I get in the logcat :

```
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211): java.io.IOException: offset < 0: -241
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:598)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.isSPDValid(SPDChecker.java:70)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.access$000(SPDChecker.java:10)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:149)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:137)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211): java.io.IOException: offset < 0: -307
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:598)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.isSPDValid(SPDChecker.java:70)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.access$000(SPDChecker.java:10)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:149)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:137)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-28 09:35:27.810: W/System.err(8211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211): java.io.IOException: offset < 0: -1005
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:598)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.isSPDValid(SPDChecker.java:70)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.access$000(SPDChecker.java:10)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:149)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:137)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211): java.io.IOException: offset < 0: -1001
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:598)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.isSPDValid(SPDChecker.java:70)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.access$000(SPDChecker.java:10)
07-28 09:35:27.820: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:149)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:137)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211): java.io.IOException: offset < 0: -106
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:598)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.isSPDValid(SPDChecker.java:70)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.access$000(SPDChecker.java:10)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:149)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:137)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-28 09:35:27.830: W/System.err(8211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-28 09:35:27.830: D/dalvikvm(24632): GC_EXPLICIT freed 304K, 62% free 5475K/14176K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 28ms
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211): java.io.IOException: offset < 0: -366
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:598)
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.isSPDValid(SPDChecker.java:70)
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker.access$000(SPDChecker.java:10)
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:149)
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at com.sec.samsung.gallery.app.imagenote.photonote.SPDChecker$1.call(SPDChecker.java:137)
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-28 09:35:27.840: W/System.err(8211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I would like to be able to remove these messages, and be able to see mines.
If you have any information or solution, thanks you for sharing it.

Comment: its not releated to your application so relax but wait its your device

Comment: Make sure all of your `Log` method calls use a TAG with your app package format. Example `com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity`, `com.mycompany.myapp.MyService`. You can then set a filter when looking at logcat such as `com.mycompany.myapp.*`

Comment: The problem is that it spams so much that my logcat becomes full, so it deletes "old" messages, including the ones of my application. I filter by application, but I can see the messages during like, one or two seconds.